# Azure DevOps add custom Tab to Build Summary

Tags: azure-devops

I want to add a custom tab to my build summary.

[image]

Inside these tab I want to display the results of the **PowerShell Test Code Coverage** task. The results are about 50-200 `*.htm` reports generated by [ReportGenerator](https://github.com/danielpalme/ReportGenerator).

I try to achive with `Write-Host "##vso[task.addattachment type=Distributedtask.Core.Summary;name=Report;]$localFile"` but the amount of reports make this option not senseful.

---

Best case solution would be, if could display the reports like:

> **AssemblyNameA.dll `collapsed:true`**
>
> ```
> index.htm collapsed:false
>     TargetAssemblyA.htm
>     TargetAssemblyB.htm
>     TargetAssemblyC.htm
> ```
>
> **AssemblyNameB.dll `collapsed:false`**
>
> ```
> index.htm collapsed:false
>     TargetAssemblyA.htm
>     TargetAssemblyB.htm
>     TargetAssemblyC.htm
> ```

---

**Is there a way to implement that?**

Comment: Try to check out [vstest task](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/VsTestV2) on github. In [testselectorinvoker.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/0d27c91b8292be67298ee4167f273d2a10f9de09/Tasks/VsTestV2/testselectorinvoker.ts#L205) I found the function `uploadTestResults`. But I don't check how the publishing works extectly. Have somebody experiance with writing extensions?

Answer (score 4):

> Azure DevOps add custom Tab to Build Summary

First, I suppose you are using Azure DevOps Server 2019. Am I right? This is a known issue for Azure DevOps Server 2019:

[Code coverage tab missing in Azure DevOps Server](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/578111/code-coverage-tab-missing-in-azure-devops-server.html)

> A fix for this issue has been released! Install the most recent
>   release from https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.

Second, if you want to create a real custom summary tab, just like Wouter said, you need to write an extension by [Visual Studio Services Web Extension SDK](https://github.com/Microsoft/vss-web-extension-sdk).

MS team has provided a great sample on github [Build Results Enhancer](https://github.com/microsoft/vsts-extension-samples/tree/master/build-results-enhancer), you can check this sample for some more details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your response. Yes you are right it is a Azure DevOps Server 2019 version **17.143.28912.1 (AzureDevOps2019.0.1)**. Currently I try to devolop a custom extension. Maybe you know which [extension type](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/blob/master/docs/extend/reference/targets/overview.md) I need to realize a custom `Test Result Tab`. I check out `ms.vss-test-web.test-result-details-tab-items` but this is only a tab for a single test result (`BuildIs > Build Entry > Tests Tab > Failed Test Entry > Panel open > Tab next to Debug.. Work Elements..`)

Answer (score 0):

To publish the coverage reports created by ReportGenerator you can use the [Publish Code Coverage Results](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/publish-code-coverage-results?view=azure-devops)  task. You need to make sure the format that ReportGenerator creates matches to what the Publish Code Coverage Results task expects.

Comment: thanks for your response. The Publish Code Coverage Results task could be a solution but, lets say I still want to create a real **custom** summary tab. Do you have an approach how it works? Extensions? Plugins?

Comment: Publish Code Coverage creates a Coverage tab. If you want a custom summary tab, that's only possible with an extension.

Comment: I've created Code Coverage and other Unit Test results pages from tools that were not compatible with TFS/VSTS/ADO.  What I did was reverse-engineer the FILE FORMAT that was expected in order to publish the results.  There might be some 3rd party tools already to assist.  But you just might have to find an already working CodeCoverage or MSTest output that is successfully published and then create a similar XML formatted file with your test results and then publish that.  Then it will show up in a new tab in the build summary page as you expect.  It worked for me in the past.

Comment: @Antebios thanks for you response, thats sound exectly what I need. Correct me if I am wrong. The **VsTest** task upload a `{username}{worker}{date}.trx` file. This file is based on a `xml` format and get used to display all these charts about succeeded and failed tests. But how could I mimic these file to display my own stuff?