# Adding a new tab with HTML content in Azure DevOps build result

Tags: azure-devops

I want to add a custom tab in the Azure DevOps build results page, next to the `Summary` tab.

[image]

Exactly the same questions were asked by different users in 2019. But the sample repo shared is outdated and never updated for more than 5 years.

https://github.com/microsoft/vsts-extension-samples/tree/master/build-results-enhancer

What is the extension points to be used for the same?

All other searches point to the same old repo.

- [Azure DevOps add custom Tab to Build Summary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57587931/azure-devops-add-custom-tab-to-build-summary)

Comment: What makes you think the old answers are incorrect? You need to write an extension. The extension API is the same.

Comment: I was under impression that the old official repository does not compile anymore as there has been changes. It's not maintained too. This was my reason. It does not compile in my laptop as there is no updated examples available in the new examples repo.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the newest documentation on extension development using the [Azure DevOps Extension SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/azure-devops/develop/extensions). The new [Azure DevOps extension sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-devops-extension-sample) uses a new [Azure DevOps SDK](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-devops-extension-sdk) along with the React-based components in the Azure DevOps UI library described in this site.

Comment: The new SDK samples does not have examples for the extension point which I am looking for. I have installed the samples in my instance and tried.